# Как правильно реализовать список?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

Не могу понять как правильно сделать такой список. Должно быть максимум 3 колонки и расположение элементов сверху вниз, а потом слева направо. Если делаю через css grid, колонок всегда 3, но расположение их мне не подходит, так как те ссылки, которые с дифисом, это подгруппа заголовка, который над ними, а при таком расположении они идут не один под другим, а по разным колонкам . Если делать через flex, то размещение правильное, а вот проблема в том, что колонок не 3, а больше, также с помощью этого метода появляется нижний скролл, а не боковой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Реализация на Grid**:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height: 375px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 01</li>
  <li>Item 02</li>
  <li>Item 03</li>
  <li>Item 04</li>
  <li>Item 05</li>
  <li>Item 06</li>
  <li>Item 07</li>
  <li>Item 08</li>
  <li>Item 09</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
  <li>Item 24</li>
  <li>Item 25</li>
  <li>Item 26</li>
  <li>Item 27</li>
  <li>Item 28</li>
  <li>Item 29</li>
  <li>Item 30</li>
  <li>Item 31</li>
  <li>Item 32</li>
  <li>Item 33</li>
  <li>Item 34</li>
  <li>Item 35</li>
  <li>Item 36</li>
  <li>Item 37</li>
  <li>Item 38</li>
  <li>Item 39</li>
  <li>Item 40</li>
  <li>Item 41</li>
  <li>Item 42</li>
  <li>Item 43</li>
  <li>Item 44</li>
  <li>Item 45</li>
  <li>Item 46</li>
  <li>Item 47</li>
  <li>Item 48</li>
  <li>Item 49</li>
  <li>Item 50</li>
  <li>Item 51</li>
  <li>Item 52</li>
  <li>Item 53</li>
  <li>Item 54</li>
  <li>Item 55</li>
  <li>Item 56</li>
  <li>Item 57</li>
  <li>Item 58</li>
  <li>Item 59</li>
  <li>Item 60</li>
  <li>Item 61</li>
  <li>Item 62</li>
  <li>Item 63</li>
  <li>Item 64</li>
  <li>Item 65</li>
  <li>Item 66</li>
  <li>Item 67</li>
  <li>Item 68</li>
  <li>Item 69</li>
  <li>Item 70</li>
  <li>Item 71</li>
  <li>Item 72</li>
  <li>Item 73</li>
  <li>Item 74</li>
  <li>Item 75</li>
  <li>Item 76</li>
  <li>Item 77</li>
  <li>Item 78</li>
  <li>Item 79</li>
  <li>Item 80</li>
  <li>Item 81</li>
  <li>Item 82</li>
  <li>Item 83</li>
  <li>Item 84</li>
  <li>Item 85</li>
  <li>Item 86</li>
  <li>Item 87</li>
  <li>Item 88</li>
  <li>Item 89</li>
  <li>Item 90</li>
  <li>Item 91</li>
  <li>Item 92</li>
  <li>Item 93</li>
  <li>Item 94</li>
  <li>Item 95</li>
  <li>Item 96</li>
  <li>Item 97</li>
  <li>Item 98</li>
  <li>Item 99</li>
</ul>
```

**Реализация на Flex**:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 375px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 01</li>
  <li>Item 02</li>
  <li>Item 03</li>
  <li>Item 04</li>
  <li>Item 05</li>
  <li>Item 06</li>
  <li>Item 07</li>
  <li>Item 08</li>
  <li>Item 09</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
  <li>Item 24</li>
  <li>Item 25</li>
  <li>Item 26</li>
  <li>Item 27</li>
  <li>Item 28</li>
  <li>Item 29</li>
  <li>Item 30</li>
  <li>Item 31</li>
  <li>Item 32</li>
  <li>Item 33</li>
  <li>Item 34</li>
  <li>Item 35</li>
  <li>Item 36</li>
  <li>Item 37</li>
  <li>Item 38</li>
  <li>Item 39</li>
  <li>Item 40</li>
  <li>Item 41</li>
  <li>Item 42</li>
  <li>Item 43</li>
  <li>Item 44</li>
  <li>Item 45</li>
  <li>Item 46</li>
  <li>Item 47</li>
  <li>Item 48</li>
  <li>Item 49</li>
  <li>Item 50</li>
  <li>Item 51</li>
  <li>Item 52</li>
  <li>Item 53</li>
  <li>Item 54</li>
  <li>Item 55</li>
  <li>Item 56</li>
  <li>Item 57</li>
  <li>Item 58</li>
  <li>Item 59</li>
  <li>Item 60</li>
  <li>Item 61</li>
  <li>Item 62</li>
  <li>Item 63</li>
  <li>Item 64</li>
  <li>Item 65</li>
  <li>Item 66</li>
  <li>Item 67</li>
  <li>Item 68</li>
  <li>Item 69</li>
  <li>Item 70</li>
  <li>Item 71</li>
  <li>Item 72</li>
  <li>Item 73</li>
  <li>Item 74</li>
  <li>Item 75</li>
  <li>Item 76</li>
  <li>Item 77</li>
  <li>Item 78</li>
  <li>Item 79</li>
  <li>Item 80</li>
  <li>Item 81</li>
  <li>Item 82</li>
  <li>Item 83</li>
  <li>Item 84</li>
  <li>Item 85</li>
  <li>Item 86</li>
  <li>Item 87</li>
  <li>Item 88</li>
  <li>Item 89</li>
  <li>Item 90</li>
  <li>Item 91</li>
  <li>Item 92</li>
  <li>Item 93</li>
  <li>Item 94</li>
  <li>Item 95</li>
  <li>Item 96</li>
  <li>Item 97</li>
  <li>Item 98</li>
  <li>Item 99</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' Добавил, вот только не знаю чем это может помочь, код там простой. По сути нужно, чтобы скролл работал как в 1 примере, а расположение элементов по колонкам как в 2.

Comment: Привет. Хочу уточнить, элементы должны в колонке идти сверху вниз, а колонки слева направо, да? А скролл должен быть горизонтальный?

Comment: @hot_penguin Да

Comment: тогда почему ты выбрал правильным решением то, в котором скролл - вертикальный, хотя в моем решение он - горизонтальный, как ты и хотел

Comment: @hot_penguin Извини, я перепутал значение горизонтально и вертикально, но в любом случае, на скрине было показано как должно быть и ответ на первую часть вопроса - Да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благо в CSS есть возможность создания "Многоколоночного текста" (Газетный текст).
Это как раз то самое поведение, когда текст располагается сверху-вниз и слева-направо в несколько колонок, то есть вот так:

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Основные свойства:

[column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) — устанавливает оптимальное число колонок.
[column-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) — расстояние между колонками.
[column-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) — оптимальная ширина колонок.
[column-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/column-rule) — разделительная линия между колонками.

Подробнее - [CSS Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns)

---

Пример на основе вашего вопроса

```js
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  document.querySelector('.list').innerHTML += `<li>item ${i+1}</li>`;
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  /**/
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: auto;
}

.list li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что нужно. Я пробовал через column сделать, но без обертки (.wrap), поэтому не получалось.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с горизонтальным скролом

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 8em;
  /* количество элементов в одном столбце (ну, или почти) */
  width: 100%;
  /* на всю ширину родительского блока */
  overflow: scroll;
  /* включаем горизонтальную прокрутку */
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  /* чтобы изменить значение 1em, нужно задать font-size для ul, тогда это значение унаследует и li */
  width: calc(100%/3);
  /* ширина столбца */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 01</li>
  <li>Item 02</li>
  <li>Item 03</li>
  <li>Item 04</li>
  <li>Item 05</li>
  <li>Item 06</li>
  <li>Item 07</li>
  <li>Item 08</li>
  <li>Item 09</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
  <li>Item 18</li>
  <li>Item 19</li>
  <li>Item 20</li>
  <li>Item 21</li>
  <li>Item 22</li>
  <li>Item 23</li>
  <li>Item 24</li>
  <li>Item 25</li>
  <li>Item 26</li>
  <li>Item 27</li>
  <li>Item 28</li>
  <li>Item 29</li>
  <li>Item 30</li>
  <li>Item 31</li>
  <li>Item 32</li>
  <li>Item 33</li>
  <li>Item 34</li>
  <li>Item 35</li>
  <li>Item 36</li>
  <li>Item 37</li>
  <li>Item 38</li>
  <li>Item 39</li>
  <li>Item 40</li>
  <li>Item 41</li>
  <li>Item 42</li>
  <li>Item 43</li>
  <li>Item 44</li>
  <li>Item 45</li>
  <li>Item 46</li>
  <li>Item 47</li>
  <li>Item 48</li>
  <li>Item 49</li>
  <li>Item 50</li>
  <li>Item 51</li>
  <li>Item 52</li>
  <li>Item 53</li>
  <li>Item 54</li>
  <li>Item 55</li>
  <li>Item 56</li>
  <li>Item 57</li>
  <li>Item 58</li>
  <li>Item 59</li>
  <li>Item 60</li>
  <li>Item 61</li>
  <li>Item 62</li>
  <li>Item 63</li>
  <li>Item 64</li>
  <li>Item 65</li>
  <li>Item 66</li>
  <li>Item 67</li>
  <li>Item 68</li>
  <li>Item 69</li>
  <li>Item 70</li>
  <li>Item 71</li>
  <li>Item 72</li>
  <li>Item 73</li>
  <li>Item 74</li>
  <li>Item 75</li>
  <li>Item 76</li>
  <li>Item 77</li>
  <li>Item 78</li>
  <li>Item 79</li>
  <li>Item 80</li>
  <li>Item 81</li>
  <li>Item 82</li>
  <li>Item 83</li>
  <li>Item 84</li>
  <li>Item 85</li>
  <li>Item 86</li>
  <li>Item 87</li>
  <li>Item 88</li>
  <li>Item 89</li>
  <li>Item 90</li>
  <li>Item 91</li>
  <li>Item 92</li>
  <li>Item 93</li>
  <li>Item 94</li>
  <li>Item 95</li>
  <li>Item 96</li>
  <li>Item 97</li>
  <li>Item 98</li>
  <li>Item 99</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Чтобы добавлять сниппет (воспроизводимый код), есть иконка "кода" (справа от иконки "пейзажа") - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/TOTjU6K.png)